# HTACCESS Redirect if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!='/oversmart/') How it could be?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

> /* NOTE : I Search 3 hour and looked other stackoverflow Questions i
>   couldn't solve it soo Please dont vote down because s.o.f. bans on
>   2-3 vote down. */

I tried the code below It should work but that doesn't work for me.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/oversmart/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /oversmart/ [QSA,L]
```

I want Redirect all to /oversmart/ folder || only $_GET variables allowed. Examples : /oversmart/ [Dont Redirect] , /oversmart/?p=profile [dont redirect] , /oversmart/index.php or /oversmart/asdsfdq2332 [Redirect to /oversmart/ folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in `/oversmart/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /oversmart/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ /oversmart/ [L]
```

`QSA` flag isn't needed here since you are not changing query string in your rule.

Comment: i copy paste that code to htacess but not working it.i think its about apache config settings. Can you help on Team Viewer ?

Comment: http://localhost/oversmart/asdsfdq2332  - object doesn't exists. || .htaccess file is in localhost/oversmart/.htaccess

Comment: trying right now 
Internal Server Error - The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. 
but gives this error if i delete DirectoryIndex os-index.php it works but shows list of files in folder.

Comment: it helped but not true answer. and why you vote down ? copy the answer i sended and i will mark it as answer. i will report you. you down vote for nothing. i was think indian people is good and you turn down my thoughts.

Comment: Excuse me??? What do you mean by voted down? I didn't vote down your question. If you want  I can downvote to prove it and you'll get -2 downvotes.

Comment: However you shouldn't have posted an answer by taking all help from me to solve your problem.

Comment: hmm sorry i take back my words. forgive me. i banned 3-4 times i am agressive about vote downers.  Can i check who down vote the question ?

Comment: i can delete answer copy and update your answer i will delete mine